# How to interpret the non-relativistic limit of $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Classical non-relativistic newtonian mechanics can be derived from special relativity by letting the speed of light tend to infinity $c \rightarrow \infty $. But doing this for Einsteins famous formula
$$
E = mc^2
$$
would yield
$$
E = \infty
$$
This would mean, that in classical mechanics the rest energy is infinite? Or how does one interpret this fact? Or should one rather look at $m =\frac{E}{c^2}$ and conclude that in classical mechanics the rest mass of a particle must be zero?

Comment: there is some controversy among the laity (the physics priesthood seems to have little disagreement) about the use of terms *"relativistic"* and *"rest"* as modifiers to the term *"mass"*.  turns out that photons, if they really **do** move at the speed of $c$, can have no rest mass (a.k.a. *"invariant mass"*) because they would have infinite energy if they did.  but they **do** have relativistic mass of $\frac{E}{c^2} = \frac{h \nu}{c^2}$ (for those to do not deprecate that term) and **everyone** agrees that they have momentum of $p=\frac{h \nu}{c}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In relativity, the absolute value of the energy of an object is important and measurable, because it contributes to the object's inertia by $E = mc^2$, as you wrote. But outside of relativity, energy and mass have no relation whatsoever. So it doesn't matter what the rest mass contribution to energy is, even if it's formally infinite -- we can just subtract it out, and nothing changes.

However, we do need to make sure that *changes* in energy agree. To do this, we need to use the full relativistic energy formula
$$E = \gamma mc^2 = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
which applies to moving bodies as well as stationary ones. Performing a Taylor expansion in $v/c$, 
$$E = mc^2 + \frac12 mc^2 \frac{v^2}{c^2} + O(v^4/c^4)$$
which approaches $mc^2 + mv^2/2$ in the nonrelativistic limit. Subtracting out the constant rest energy contribution, we find $E = mv^2/2$, as we should.

Comment: But isn't the non-relativistic limit is $\infty + mv^2/2$? This substraction of a formally infinite, but constant quantity reminds me a bit of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization. Is this the same idea here?

Comment: @asmaier I would say it's somewhat different. Renormalization is usually applied to physically measurable quantities. But the absolute value of the energy is never measurable in non-relativistic mechanics in the first place, so there is no 'physical infinity' to deal with.